# Printing two dimensional array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with my code for printing the two dimensional array

```
int[][] container = new int [3][6];
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j <== 6; j++) {
        System.out.print(contianer[i][j] + " ");
    }
}
System.out.println();
```

Comment: Your conditions should be `i < 3` and `j < 6`. `<==` isn't even an operator.

Comment: Isn't the compiler telling you?

Comment: For future reference, please read through [ask] before asking a question here. If something is wrong with your code, _explain_ why you think it is wrong. Does it give errors? Then add the errors to the question. Is the output different from what you expected? Add the actual and expected outputs to the question.

Comment: @khelwood sorry <== was a typo should be <= 6

Answer (score 1):

- `<==`is not an operator.
- Array start from 0 to `length - 1`
- you have a typo in your variable inside the `for`
- `System.out.println();`must be executed inside the first `for` not outside.

```java
int[][] container = new int [3][6];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        System.out.print(container[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```